# Modern-UI JSon Total Days Calculation in a custom-list allitems view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, jslink, json, modern-experience

I needed to show the day the item is in open status. The days are only displayed in allitem.aspx. I was able to use JSLink to achieve it in classic UI. When the user switches to Modern UI, JSLink does not work, I modified it to Json to see if it works.

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=if((Number([$Date_x0020_Closed]) == 0), 
           ((Number(Date(@now)))/86400000-
                     (Number([$Date_x0020_Opened]))/86400000), 
           ((Number([$Date_x0020_Closed]))/86400000-
                     (Number([$Date_x0020_Opened]))/86400000))"
}
```

This gives me the values in decimal. How do I convert it to total days without decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculate column set return type as Number with 0 decimal.

Sample formula: `=NOW()-[Date Opened]`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the update. I thought the calculated column gets updated only when the item is updated. Does the value changes everyday even if the list item is not updated/modified?

Comment: That would be a issue, you may use Flow https://sharepointlibrarian.com/2017/12/08/use-microsoft-flow-to-create-a-today-column-for-use-in-sharepoint-list-calculations/